# Taking the address of boost::hana::partial::operator()

Tags: c++, c++14, function-pointers, boost-hana

Suppose I have a lambda that does something:

```
auto thing = [](int x){ /* Stuff */ };
```

I want to save off the value "x" and call it later so I do:

```
auto other = boost::hana::partial(thing, 42);
```

Now, because I want to do some type erasure on this I want to take the address of the `operator()`.....so I try to do this:

```
using type = decltype(other);
void (type::*ptr)(void) = &type::operator();
```

Clang complains, that the `other` object does not a sufficient function that matches the requirements: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/Ncjvp2)

It appears that the `partial` type is returning a reference (to `void`?)......why does this not work?

Comment: Why specify `void (type::*ptr)(void)` at all?  Why not just `auto ptr = &type::operator();`?  +1 for using Boost Hana.

Comment: @Eljay I need to specify the type, because this is actually deep inside a template monster that needs to be able to handle overloads (which means the type needs to be specified)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It (the operator()) has `&` `const&` `&&` etc overloads; your member function pointer does not qualify `*this` by const or r/l value-ness.  So does not match.

Add `&` or `const&` or `&&` or `const&&` before `=` on the line that fails to compile, and it will compile.

Here is a [MCVE]:

```
struct foo {
    void bar()&{}
};

int main(){
    auto p = &foo::bar;
    void(foo::*p2)() = p; // lacks &
}
```